# jquery local content not showing up in all cluetips

Tags: javascript, jquery, cluetip

i'm working on a site which uses jquery v1.6.2. i want to show a cluetip using local content for all anchors of a given class. however the localcontent in the cluetip is only showing up for the first two anchors of this class. i have simplified the problem down to the following code: ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3d9k/))

```
$(function() {
    $('a.triggerxxx').cluetip({
        activation: "click",
        cluetipClass: "jtip",
        local: true,
        hideLocal: true,
        sticky: true
    });
});

<a class="triggerxxx" href="#" title="cluetip title" rel="div.cluetip-contentxxx">trigger text 1</a><br>
<a class="triggerxxx" href="#" title="cluetip title" rel="div.cluetip-contentxxx">trigger text 2</a><br>
<a class="triggerxxx" href="#" title="cluetip title" rel="div.cluetip-contentxxx">trigger text 3</a><br>
<a class="triggerxxx" href="#" title="cluetip title" rel="div.cluetip-contentxxx">trigger text 4</a>
<div class="cluetip-contentxxx">this content should show in all cluetips, but it only shows up in the first two</div>
```

is cluetip not meant to work this way, or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('a.triggerxxx').each(function(index) {
       $(this).cluetip({
        activation: "click",
        cluetipClass: "jtip",
        local: true,
        hideLocal: true,
        sticky: true
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. its weird that it just half worked the original way, but didn't fail completely. i would have expected the cluetip to only get applied to either the first or the last trigger the original way if it was going to fail at all.

Comment: yeah I couldn't figure that out. It only worked if you clicked 1 then 2. If you went 4,3,2,1 or 1,3 it would only show the tip on the first one.

Comment: yeah. i think it must be a bug. the method you give here avoids the problem anyhow.